# Making a sortable a table in Doxygen, adding a class to a table

Tags: html, css, doxygen, jquery-ui-sortable

I've found a really easy javascript to client-side sort an html table [sorttable](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/), just add the javascript `sorttable.js`.  This is easily added to the custom header file.  Then and add the word `sortable` to the class of the table `<table class="doxtable sortable">`

That 2nd point though: The manual modification is easy enough, but my tables are in markdown and I can't specify an ID or class. I'm looking for a way to automate it.  Ideally I would like to specify which tables are sortable, but would settle for all of them.

1. I was wondering if I could add the `sortable` class to the `doxtable` class in the style sheet (That might be a dumb question, probably html classes can not be combined like that).
2. Using html instead of markdown would work, but makes for more cryptic source code comments.  Aliases might help simplify the source, but I'd rather not get too convoluted.
3. Post processing search and replace

   - of `<table class="doxtable">`
   - to `<table class="doxtable sortable">`

Comment: How do you determine which tables are sortable?

Comment: I have don't have a good idea how to specify/determine which tables are sortable.  That's kind of a rhetorical part of the question, as I'm sure markdown has nothing for that.

Comment: What I mean is, outside of code what is the determining factor for deciding if a table is sortable? If you don't want them all sortable what would make you say this one is and this one isn't.

Comment: I can't imagine a solid criteria to decide.  It is my tables for test code coverage that I wanted to be able to sort.  Then there is table of file names, which has no need to be sorted but no harm in doing so.  I don't want the table of enums to be sortable as their order is important.